# Firebase onDisconnected called when closing the app by swiping it out

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I got an app which uses Firebase.

The Firebase's records holds a "status" field which is supposed to give information if the user is offline or online.

I initialize it like that:

```
fireBase = new Firebase("https://myProj.firebaseio.com/users");
child = fireBase.child(MyApp.myStringIdentifier);
child.child("status").setValue(ClientStatus.ONLINE);
child.child("status").onDisconnect().setValue(ClientStatus.OFFLINE);
```

The initialization works fine, and the `onDisconnect()` is also called after a lot of time there's no internet connection and firebase does change the status to offline as expected.

The problem is that the `onDisconnect` event is also called when the user swipes out the app from the recent apps list, but I want the user to remain online since I got services which are still running in the background which should handle some events even when the app is closed (They are still running, but other users get the offline status of the closing user and then the actions to that user are blocked) .

Is there a way to prevent to `onDisconnect` event to be called when the user swipes out the app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `onDisconnect` handlers of your Firebase Database client are called:

1. when the database client actively disconnects from the Firebase server
2. when the server detects that the database client has disappeared (by the socket connection timing out)

Note that neither of these has anything to do with your application lifecycle, which seems to be what you are interested in.

If you want to change the database when your application is destroyed, you should probably listen to application lifecycle events to [detect when the application exits](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bandroid%5D+detect+application+exit).

Comment: I need a way to know the difference between disconnection due to reason 1 or reason 2 of what you wrote.. with reason 2 I will assume the user got no internet connection at all, but with reason 1 I want to assume that the app was killed but there are still services alive which can handle incoming events.

Comment: Is it possible to know the reason (1 or 2 of what you wrote) why was the onDisconnect event called?

Comment: There is no way to know whether the disconnect event fires for a active disconnect or a timeout on the socket. All that you can rely on is that the client was disconnected.

Answer (score 2):

When the user of an Android devices uses the overview display to "swipe away" an app, that's a signal that they don't want to use the app any more, and they're not interested in returning to it any time soon.  Android will kill the app process.  Killing the app process will close the connection that it has to your Realtime Database.  Closing the connection will cause onDisconnect() to execute on the server.  You have no control over this process when the user makes their decision.  This is by design of the Android platform, which is to allow the user to make the final decision about what can actually run on their device. As the app developer, you are not empowered to force your own decision on the matter.

If you want to send the app a message even though it's been killed by the user, you can instead use [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) to deliver events that the user has expressed interest in.

Comment: The problem is not with sending a message, but to let other users know you're online. Every client repeatedly get the status of all other clients from firebase and then they think the swiping away user is offline, even though he got services which can handle events from him.

Comment: You may want to instead ask a new question about the implementation of your specific requirements for what it means for a user to "be online", in whatever way you define that (it's not clear to me, and Android also does not define this).  If you're trying to define it in terms of the device's network connectivity, your app will not really be able to depend on that on newer devices.  Your app process simply cannot be running all the time.